# something very strange happening in javascript object construction

Tags: javascript

This is really bizarre. I've created an image handling object that stores an array of images and displays them on a page, among other methods. However, for some reason it's behaving really strangely. Here's a console log from chrome:

```
default constructor imgHandler.js:16
[null] imgHandler.js:17
GET http://localhost:8080/cglst/images/null 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
    f.fn.extend.html jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
    e.extend.access jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
    f.fn.extend.html jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
    update imgHandler.js:65
    $.ajax.success addform.php:239
    f.Callbacks.o jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
    f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
    w jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
    f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
```

and so here's the constructor in imgHandler.js:

```
function imgHandler(imgString) {
    if (imgString != null && imgString != "null") {
        this.img = imgString.split(",");
        this.size = this.img.length;
        console.log("parametrized constructor")
        console.log(this.img);
    } else {
        this.img = Array("defaultimage.png");
        this.size = 0;
        console.log("default constructor")
        console.log(this.img);
    }
```

And here are lines 238-240 of addform.php:

```
                    imgHandle = new imgHandler(data.results[0].photos);
                    imgHandle.update();
                    updatePreview();
```

I have no idea how this is possible, since I set `this.img` to an array of one image filename literally two lines before `console.log("default constructor")`...

Comment: Whats contained in imgHandle.update() && updatePreview()?  It looks like the error comes from one of those. If its a constructor problem don't run those functions and see what the console says.

Comment: There aren't any immediate problems here that would cause your given console.log [null] value.  I have lots of nits here, but no errors beyond not including the closing brace for the imgHandler function (which I'm sure exists in your code, as you'd be describing a different problem otherwise).  See if you can reproduce the problem on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and post it.